# Is there a standard naming convention for keysets, column families, and column names

Tags: cassandra

I am new to this technology, I have a hard time to find answer to this basic question.
Is there widely adopted naming convention for keysets, column families and column names,
such as

- PascalCase
- camelCase
- snake_case
- alllowercase

Project I am looking at is using alllowercase, so I am wondering if there is a reason behind it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should be good with anything that is all lower case. Anything with mixed case will need to be explicitly escaped "StRinG" or else it will be automatically lowercased. I like snake_case but thats just a personal preference.